# Laravel remember token not clearing [5.7]

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application I am using an additional guard called `admin` that has its own model and database table.

I define it in **/config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 15,
    ],
],
```

Then I essentially copy everything from **http/controllers/auth** to **http/controllers/auth/admin**. Specifically the LoginController, ForgotPasswordController and ResetPasswordController.

I then override the necessary methods to use the guard as `Auth::guard('admin');`

Now, everything works as expected apart from one thing: as an admin, if I tick 'Remember me' on the login form it generates a token like so:

[image]

As you can see the remember token also references the guard, if I were to sign in using the normal auth guard it would read like `_web_`

Interestingly though, when I logout the redirect happens but the remember token persists, this does not occur with users.

Below is an example of a user remember token that uses the web guard:

[image]

I can see that the LoginController uses AuthenticatesUses in this line:

`use AuthenticatesUsers;`

Which has a protected method that I am overriding in my LoginController as below:

```
/**
 * Define the guard to use for the Authenticated users trait, in this case admin
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

As you can see, I believe I've done everything as it should be done but I can't see anywhere that actually clears the remember_token.